# QSetttings IniFormat ends up in Registry

Tags: qt, registry, ini, qsettings

I am saving app data in Ini file. Here is how:

```
QSettings IniFile(K_COMPNAME,K_INIFILENAME);
QSettings::setDefaultFormat(QSettings::IniFormat);
IniFile.setValue("Location",loc);
IniFile.setValue("BaudRate",baud);
IniFile.sync();
```

K_INIFILENAME is a constant "Settings".

I would expect a Settings.ini in same folder as my exe.
But no. Instead this is saved in Registry. Cause when I do
`qDebug() << IniFile.fileName();` it returns:

> "\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyCompany\Settings"

My question is why is it so, and how to make it save in Ini file.

Comment: You were probably downvoted because you didn't read the documentation before posting a question. It's my guess. By the way, you use `QSettings` constructor wrongly - there is no such constructor that gets a company name and file name. In your case Qt treats `K_INIFILENAME` as application name.

Comment: I did read the documentation. But I did not understand it so much. Maybe they need to improve the documentation fformat so it is easier to understand with clearcut examples? Idk.

Comment: And also, if the answer to all stackoverflow questions is "read the documentation", then might as well delete stackoveflow altogether. The reason people ask in SO normally is because they HAVE read the documentation, tried it the wrong way (because they misunderstood or something). It is funny Qt community. If you are unwilling to help, just don't reply anything and let others who are willing to help answer it.

Comment: Please take it easy. Everyone here wants to help to solve problems. I hope so. However when someone sees no effort - it can be a reason for downvoting. You can read a long discussion on this topic here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question .

Comment: That is just one discussion. Which does not make it a law. I always hold to the stance that "If you don't want to help just go away". It is a simple concept that people should learn. I am not abusing the forum. I am not asking stupid things. I am legitimately asking for help/guide. If you feel it is too simple for your mighty powerful knowledge, then just leave!

Comment: So you don't accept the fact that others can have different opinion on your question? Downvoting doesn't mean your questions shouldn't be answered, indeed. It's just indication on how good and useful the question is. This is what "downvote" button is for and how this community works. Finally, if you think I downvoted you - I didn't. I just tried to answer on your question and explain things.

Comment: Downvoting DOES mean my question has a less chance to be answered! Because when you downvote, people less likely to click on it when in fact there is no problem with it. I did not say you downvoted me either. You assumed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

keep in mind that with constructor:

```
QSettings IniFile(K_COMPNAME,K_INIFILENAME);
```

> Constructs a QSettings object for accessing settings of the
>   application called **application** from the organization called
>   **organization**,
>
> The scope is set to QSettings::UserScope, and the format is set to
>   QSettings::NativeFormat (i.e. **calling setDefaultFormat()** before
>   calling this constructor **has no effect**).

Which means its a registry valid constructor (under windows) .. 
The right approach for INI format would be:

```
QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName(K_COMPNAME);
QCoreApplication::setApplicationName(K_INIFILENAME);
QSettings::setDefaultFormat(QSettings::IniFormat);
QSettings IniFile;
```

The above code will use INI format and the settings are stored in `FOLDERID_RoamingAppData`

For example:  `FOLDERID_RoamingAppData\<K_COMPNAME>\<K_INIFILENAME>`

now there is only one another constructor to store in local INI (`settings.ini`) file like this:

```
QSettings IniFile(K_INIFILENAME,QSettings::IniFormat);
```

Comment: I would like to say thank you very much for your time to help and guide me in this topic. Have a good day Sir!

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#QSettings) of the `QSettings` constructor states:

> Use setDefaultFormat() before calling this constructor
>   to change the default format used by this constructor.

Therefore, call `setDefaultFormat` before creating your `QSettings` object:

```
QSettings::setDefaultFormat(QSettings::IniFormat);
QSettings IniFile(K_COMPNAME,K_INIFILENAME);
IniFile.setValue("Location",loc);
IniFile.setValue("BaudRate",baud);
IniFile.sync();
```